# Expand and Simplify do not work for NonCommutativeMultiply

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

Expand and Simplify do not work for NonCommutativeMultiply[] then how do we expand an expression like

(a+b)**(a-b)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this in Mathematica. I prefer a simple approach as in the following code:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
a___ ** (b_ + c_) ** d___ := a ** b ** d + a ** c ** d;
a___ ** (n_?NumericQ b_) ** c___ := n (a ** b ** c);
a__ ** (n_?NumericQ) := n a; (n_?NumericQ) ** a__ := n a;
```

which should do what you expect. For exmaple:

```
(a + b) ** (a - b) == a ** a - a ** b + b ** a - b ** b
```

evaluates to `True`. The last line of code allows the code

```
x ** 0 == 0 == 0 ** x && x ** -1 == -x == -1 ** x
```

to evaluate to `True`. Note that this solution automatically expands expressions containing `**`. If you don't want this to happen, then an alternative way to do this is to change the `:=` to `:>` instead and make them into a list of rules.

Answer (score 1):

Up to the documentation to `**`, "Expand and Simplify do not operate on expressions with NonCommutativeMultiply". According to this documentation, the following works.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &]; 
ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a]; ExpandNCM[(a + b) ** (c + d)]
```

> a**c+a**d+b**c+b**d

Comment: Thanks. Why does it give a ** a+a ** (-b)+a ** (b)+b ** (-b) as output? can we not bring - outside?

Comment: @Chetan Waghela: What was asked,that was answered. -1 for your edit of your question after my answer..

Comment: Though the edit was for better understanding, and it does not change my question. I do not care for -1. Please solve the query, as I requested in the comment. No hard feelings.

Comment: As far as I understand it, $a-b$ is treated as $a+(-b)$: a - b == a + (-b) performs True.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) instead of [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply)?

```
TensorExpand @ TensorProduct[a+b, a-b]
```

> ```
> a\[TensorProduct]a - a\[TensorProduct]b + b\[TensorProduct]a - 
> b\[TensorProduct]b
> ```

or as an image:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a nice idea. Though I hope it does not get caught in problem with some other manipulations.